# Extracting from two rasters in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, extract

I have raster A with 11 classes and raster B with 11 classes. I tried the con= tool but didn't work. I'd like to extract a new layer from something like:

> extract where raster A class >=1 and <=4 and where raster B class = 9

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Con tool will do this, you just need to spell out each expression fully and use parentheses to group your expressions correctly. Something like this:

```
Con((((rasterA >=1) & (rasterA <=4)) & rasterB = 9), 1, 0)
```

That would give you a new raster with a value of 1 wherever those conditions are true, and a zero everywhere else. Check out the [Con help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) for some other examples. You don't say what your desired output is so in order to generate something a little more complex you may need to get into nested Con statements.

Comment: Thanks for helping. The desired output is to produce an output (can be vector) where two input rasters meet specific conditions and are overlayed on one another. Specifically, I have the results of a Kriging raster and also the Kriging Variance raster. I want to select classes from the variance raster (perhaps the class with the lowest variance) and use it to cut or clip the Kriging raster based on a raster class in it.

Comment: OK, in that case you can use the Con statement I have above and when you're done, convert the resulting raster to polygon and keep the polygons that have a value of 1.